# Is there any method to detect the developer's tool and quit it?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I want to defend from script hooking by using developer's tools.
This should apply on Edge, Chrome and IE.

I found that the normal script to defend F12 is not working when you tap the address bar and click F12 key.
I need stronger code or software to defend from openning the developer's tools.

I don't care on the language, it's fine to learn new things.

Please advise me the best option.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to prevent devtools from opening via the browser UI. Intentionally so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't complete disable F12 in browsers using code. I know you want to do it in code, but the only way to disable F12 in browsers is using group policy.

In Edge, you can use this group policy [DeveloperToolsAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#developertoolsavailability), setting the policy to `DeveloperToolsDisallowed` to disable F12 devtools.

In IE, you can use the policy mentioned in the accepted answer of [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-f12-developer-tools/1f50a845-b573-475d-9984-29ba3bbd427e) to diable F12 devtools.

In Chrome, you can use this group policy [DeveloperToolsAvailability](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DeveloperToolsAvailability), setting the policy to `DeveloperToolsDisallowed` to disable F12 devtools.